# I can't find IHttpControllerActivator in asp.net core api

Tags: asp.net-core

I can't find IHttpControllerActivator in asp.net core api

```
 public class WindsorHttpControllerActivator:IHttpControllerActivator
{
    public IHttpController Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)
    {
        var instance = DependencyContainer.Resolve(controllerType);

        if (instance == null)
        {
            throw new HttpException((int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound, string.Format("{0} cannot be resolved.", controllerType.Name));
        }

        return (IHttpController) instance;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me know if this rewrite works.
There were changes to the API for third-party DI

```cs
using Castle.Windsor;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers;

public class WindsorControllerActivator : IControllerActivator
{
    private readonly IWindsorContainer _container;

    public WindsorControllerActivator(IWindsorContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public object Create(ControllerContext context)
    {
        var controllerType = context.ActionDescriptor.ControllerTypeInfo.AsType();
        var instance = _container.Resolve(controllerType);

        if (instance == null)
        {
            //throw whatever
        }

        return (ControllerBase)instance;
    }

    public void Release(ControllerContext context, object controller)
    {
        _container.Release(controller);
    }
}
```

these articles were helpful to me @ least:

https://kristian.hellang.com/third-party-dependency-injection-in-asp-net-core/

https://medium.com/@nevsnirG/manual-controller-activation-and-dependency-injection-in-asp-net-core-web-api-46aba579b0e

EDIT:
in '''Startup.cs''', don't forget the lines

```cs
services.AddSingleton<IControllerActivator>(new WindsorControllerActivator (_container));
```

Comment: however, it might be better to just not use IControllerActivator;
.NET Core's DI already takes care of these things it seems.